# Why doesn't Tkinter.Tk() open the window right away?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using Tkinter in python 2.7, and I noticed that sometimes the root window doesn't open until I start the mainloop method.
I addition, in those cases, when close the window, the program is ending (the root.mainloop is the last line in the code), and in the other cases it's not happening.

Why is it happening?

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is that it's happening because that is how it was designed to happen.

Nothing happens in tkinter except through the event loop. Even something as simple as the window appearing is the event loop responding to an event. For example, when you create the window (and assuming you don't withdraw it), a "redraw yourself" event in effect gets added to the event queue. When you start the event loop, that's one of the first events it processes and the window appears.

When you call `mainloop()`, that causes the event loop to start processing events. It is designed to start processing events and not return until the root window has been destroyed. That is why the call to `mainloop` is typically the last line of code in the file, since there's usually nothing else to do once the user has closed the window.

The other way to process events is to call `update` or `update_idletasks`. `update` will start the event loop, and return once all pending events have been processed (ie: it doesn't wait for the window to be destroyed). `update_idletasks` is similar, but only updates "idle" events: things scheduled with `after`, events related to redrawing windows, and a few others. It doesn't process user-generated events like mouse and button clicks.

Comment: Why sometimes the Tkinter.Tk() opens automatically the window, and sometimes it doesn't?

Comment: @Daniel  would argue that it never does that. I’ve never, ever seen it. Different types of environments (anaconda, interactive, etc) May differ from each other, but any given environment won’t randomly choose to behave differently. If the window appears, something causes the event loop to process events.

Comment: Python turtle, which is built atop tkinter, will show the window, perform graphics, etc. before the call to `mainloop()` (which just hands off to the same named tkinter method.)  Some turtle programs never even call `mainloop()` but display all sorts of graphics.  However, per your explanation (+1), the turtle code is littered with calls to `_update()` (i.e. internal tkinter canvas `update()`).

Comment: @cdlane: yes, turtle has different behavior than plain tkinter.

Comment: Maybe OP is referring to interactive use of tkinter in the Python shell.